# how to set multiple option value in multiple select box after refresh the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

please tell me how to set multiple option value in multiple select box after refreshing the page.

I have dynamic select box with different id like following

```
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1"/>
       <option value="a" selected="selected">Data 1</option>
       <option value="b">Data 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select_2" name="select_2"/>
       <option value="a">Data 1</option>
       <option value="b" selected="selected">Data 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="select_3" name="select_3"/>
       <option value="a" selected="selected">Data 1</option>
       <option value="b">Data 2</option>
    </select>
```

I want to selected all option values of all selectbox after refreshing the page with php and ajax.

Comment: Magic!? Select it how? Where are the values coming from? You need to provide more details.

Comment: values are comming from database.I create dynamic selectbox by selecting database values.

Comment: So you need a way to remember what was selected and reselect them.

Comment: If you're using ajax, why are you refreshing the page?

Comment: I dont want to reselect again...I want to make it in that way that wont reselect all those selected value again after refreshing the page.

Comment: I want to use in ajax as because on onchange function of each select box I will fire an ajax page and load those all selected value in session.please help.

Comment: If you are using ajax why you need to refresh the page, if you dont need to reselect check these condition in AJAX request itself and pass as result

Comment: if I go to another page of that application,and go to that page again then all the selected values will gone..that is why I want those selected value set in all select box after refreshing the page.please give any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data is populated and presented, but here's an example:

```
<?foreach($selects as $select):?>
<?$selected = ($select->Selected === true) ? 'selected="selected"' :'';?>
<select id="<?=$select->Id?>" name="<?=$select->Name?>"/>
  <?foreach($select->Options as $option):?>
  <option value="<?=$option->Value?>"<?=$selected;?>><?=$option->Text?></option> 
  <?endforeach;?>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Or

```
foreach($selects as $select)
{
  $selected = ($select->Selected === true) ? 'selected="selected"' :'';
  echo "<select id=\"{$select->Id}\" name=\"{$select->Name}\"/>\n";
  foreach($select->Options as $option)
  {
    echo "<option value=\"{$option->Value}\"{$selected}>{$option->Text}</option>\n";
  }
  echo "</select>\n";
}
```

Comment: I want like I have a shopping cart website and when I add product in to my cart,on cart page different product have different shipping country in dropdown.So if I choose different shipping country for different product on cart page and again go to the another product detail page an add to my cart..I want to show my all selected shipping country of previous product.I dont want to reselect again.please guide.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to suggest a fix to your problem, but.. In your previous comment you said: "values are comming from database.I create dynamic selectbox by selecting database values.". Can't you pull the values from the database again on the second page load? Or maybe the problem is that you're not storing the users changes in the database, in which case I would suggest using AJAX to  update the database with the user selections.